# docpad plugin cannot see collections

Tags: docpad

I'm trying to update the [DCE text editor](https://github.com/cauld/docpad-plugin-dce) plugin as it no longer seems to work out of the box. I have a Docpad setup with two collections - Dutch and English - defined in docpad.coffee below that are used by my templates.

```
# Collections 
collections:
    Dutch: ->
        @getCollection("html").findAllLive({isPage:true; lang: "Nederlands"}, {menuorder:1})
    English: ->
        @getCollection("html").findAllLive({isPage:true; lang: "English"}, {menuorder:1})
```

But the plugin (not sure whether that is the best name for it though as it is not in the plugin folder) does not find them. In the plugin's app.js, we have

```
var docpadInstanceConfiguration = {
    serverExpress: app,
    serverHttp: server,
    // Tell it not to load the standard middlewares (as we handled that above)
    middlewareStandard: false,
    rootPath: path.resolve('../../')
};
GLOBAL.docpadInstance = dpad.createInstance(docpadInstanceConfiguration, function(err){
    if (err)  return console.log(err.stack);
        docpad.action('generate server watch', function(err){
        if (err)  return console.log(err.stack);
    });
});
```

I can find a docpadInstance object in node-inspector, running app.js causes docpad to regenerate my pages, and when I seek the 'database' collection I get access to my source docs (and lots of other things), so I think this is working.

But the docpadInstance does not contain any details about the collections, and subsequent calls to `collectionItems = docpadInstance.getCollection(collectionName);`
always returns `null` when `collectionName` is set to a Dutch or English.

I'd welcome advice on further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out.
I had the collections elements within the `templateData` section of docpad.coffee, which is not in line with the documentation. That said, this mis-configuration was not not noticed by my regular setup